# Determine Slide Show Runs on Which monitor Programmatically using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, powerpoint, powerpoint-2013

I have created PowerPoint Add-in when user enables Presenter view and change monitor to primary/Monitor2 I want to detect what he selected to handle his actions.

I want to Detect Monitor on which Slide Show is running using vb.net I searched a lot Where I got some links that was asking to determine screen resolution for slide show window but no answer for detecting a monitor that is running slide show.

Comment: When the user changes the monitor, PowerPoint stores the information in its section of the registry.  IIRC, HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\PowerPoint\Options  (substitute the correct version number in place of 15.0).  I forget exactly what it's called, but it's fairly obvious, especially if you leave REGEDIT open to that section, change the PPT setting, then F5 refresh the REGEDIT window.

Comment: Thanks I have solved problem using your answer on this link http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-customize/in-a-dial-monitor-system-finding-out-on-which/6495286f-c5db-4a78-a2ca-843f7a8ef60c once again thanks